# get intentExtra image and display it in WebView

Tags: android, android-intent, android-webview

Im trying to display the image i have coming from an intent.putExtra on a listView click, into a WebView. I have it working fine if i just load it into an ImageView, but the imageview doesnt zoom and i was looking into the zoomcontrol on a wbeview

here is what i have so far:

```
 int myDrawableId = getIntent().getIntExtra("myDrawable", -1);
        WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        String data = "<body>" + "<img src=\\"file:///myDrawableId\"/></body>";
        webview.loadUrl("myDrawableId");
```

i was wondering if anyone could see what i had wrong here, because it keeps making my "file" tagged out like comments. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Noel is correct that it should be `src=\"` and not `src=\\"` but it's not going to work anyway as `myDrawableId` is an integer resource id and not a valid filename (yes, I remember your last question).

To do this simply put the image into the /res/assets folder and instead of passing the resource id in the intent pass the image filename, e.g., my_image.jpg

Example...

```
String imageName = getIntent().getStringExtra("myDrawableName");
webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/" + imageName);
```

Comment: I did not see the OP's previous question. This seems to be what they were intending to do.

Comment: @Noel: I just happened to recognise the first line of code in the OP's question - it comes from my answer to the previous one. :)

Comment: thank you that helped clear out me errors, but is there a way to display the image after that into the webview?

Comment: As you remember from my  previous post it will be a different image in the getIntentExtra depending on the listView click

Comment: im also wondering if i would have to change my Intent.putExtra to an asset instead of a drawable in my listview class

Comment: @Nick: But either way, if you are doing this based on the position of the list item that is clicked it doesn't matter if you are putting an int extra for a resource id or a string extra for the actual image name. As long as you don't have too many list items this isn't a big problem.

Comment: @Nick: Sorry, cross posted only just seen your last comment. Your previous question didn't explain what you are populating your ListView with so I'm not sure.

Comment: my listview just has ten items, each with one picture associated with the listview item, the intentPutExtra is what grabs the certain picture associated with the listview item, so when i get the intentExtra i want to display that single picture associated with the listview click in my webview

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that you are escaping the backslash and not the quote in this line:

```
    String data = "<body>" + "<img src=\\"file:///myDrawableId\"/></body>";
```

It should really be this:

```
    String data = "<body>" + "<img src=\"file:///myDrawableId\"/></body>";
```

Comment: yes that helped and made it see the file im trying to put in there but now its saying that 'data' and 'myDrawableId' are not being used, does myDrawableId have to be in quotes inside there?

Comment: See MisterSquonk's answer. I did not know what you were trying to do. Also, you should really get more familiar with Java before trying to dive into android.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you want `webview.loadUrl(data);`.

Is that it?

Comment: no the line above that is still commented out after the file:///, and the error is saying to add a semicolon

Comment: Well sure if it is commented after file:///, then you bet you must be missing a semicolon since the one at the end is part of the commented line!